# How to get innerHTML of an iframe with the latest browser versions like IE11, Chrome 71, Firefox 62(Quantum)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am using IE11, Chrome 71 and Firefox 62(Quantum) browsers. I am just experimenting with iframe to upload the file(it's not a cross domain). The same code was working fine with IE7 earlier.We are making our project a browser agnostic now. I just want to know what is the best way to get innerHTML of the iframe with latest browsers. I have tried with the following approaches, but nothing worked for me.

1)

```
iframeId = document.getElementById("upload_iframe");
        content = iframeId.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
```

2)  `$('#iframeId ').contents().find('body').innerHTML`

3) `$('#iframeId ').contents().find('body').html();`

4)

```
iframeId = document.getElementById("upload_iframe");
  iframeId.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML
```

5)

```
iframeId = document.getElementById("upload_iframe");
      iframeId.document.body.innerHTML
```

Any help is much apprecited.